# In SharePoint online, Name is the default column with its column type as File. How to rename the NAME in Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view, modern-experience, document

I am trying to create a column with NAME but I can't as Name is the default.
I tried using Content types methods but there too Name is default with it's column type as 'File'.

Kindly help me answer these questions:
So here are my questions:

1. Is there any other way to rename 'Name", So I can create another column as "Name".
2. Is it possible to create a column with its column type as "File", So I can use it to store the file name during creation/ upload?

Comment: Doesn’t work. Simply changing what name displays on a view with js or something would be beneficial to me

Answer (score 0):

Try below if it works:

Rename Name column from modern experience document library view as:

[image]

Comment: "Rename" option shown in above image might not be available currently because Microsoft removed this option for SharePoint default "Name" column recently.